# Looping through array like structure in LaTeX

Tags: amsmath, loops

Suppose I have the following latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation}
  a+b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I would like to avoid rewriting the `equation` environment for every new equation. Is it possible to do the following in LaTeX?

- Assign the equations to a variable
- Loop through the equations such that I only explicitly write the `equation` environment once

If so, how? I saw that `TikZ` does supply a for-each type command, but it seems like an overkill to import all of `TikZ` just for that, since I am not generating any diagrams.

Comment: note you should never have one `equation` after another (tex will insert spurious white paragraphs in between) this should be marked up as a single `gather` environment (or `align` if you want to align on =) and then it only needs `\\ ` between the equations

Comment: I have standard text both before and after each equation. The .tex file I provide above is just a minimum working example.

Comment: I assumed you didn't have any text (as how do you want to insert that in the loop, or do you mean it is the same text in each case?)

Comment: It's the same text in each case.

Comment: (La)TeX is not an ordinary programming language.  It seems to me that what you want can best be accomplished using an editor tailored for TeX.  There are several such, depending on the hardware/operating system you are using.  One of the goals of TeX is to have a human (as well as computer) readable input file, and what you are asking for is to cripple that goal.

Answer (score 8):

Using consecutive `equation` environments is wrong, more so if you separate them with blank lines. Use the appropriate `amsmath` environments such as `align` or `gather`.

I'm not sure that a syntax such as

```
\printequations{a+b=c \\ a^2+b^2 \\ a^2+b^2=c^2}
```

is really better than

```
\begin{gather}
a+b=c \\
a^2+b^2 \\
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{gather}
```

but you can obtain what you want in a simple way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\printequations}[1]{%
  \begin{gather}#1\end{gather}%
}

\begin{document}

\printequations{a+b=c \\ a^2+b^2 \\ a^2+b^2=c^2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer a different syntax,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{xparse}% uncomment for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printequations}{m}
 {
  \begin{gather}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {} { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ }
  \end{gather}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printequations{{a+b}{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2=c^2}}

\end{document}
```

will produce the same as before.

If your aim is to define a set of equations and use them one after the other, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{xparse}% uncomment for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_egreg_equations_list_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineequations}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_egreg_equations_list_seq {\\} { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\nextequation}{}
 {
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_egreg_equations_list_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \begin{equation}
  \l_tmpa_tl
  \end{equation}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\defineequations{a+b \\ a^2+b^2 \\ a^2+b^2=c^2}

Some text before the first equation
\nextequation
Some other text between the first and the second equation
\nextequation
Some other text between the second and third equation
\nextequation
Some final text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to index your equations here is a possibility. The kay before the `=` is an arbitrary string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{xparse}% uncomment for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineequations}{m}
 {
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_egreg_equations_list_prop { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\useequation}{m}
 {
  \begin{equation}
  \prop_item:Nn \l_egreg_equations_list_prop { #1 }
  \end{equation}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\defineequations{
 1={a+b},
 2={a^2+b^2},
 3={a^2+b^2=c^2}
}
Some text before the first equation
\useequation{2}
Some other text between the first and the second equation
\useequation{1}
Some other text between the second and third equation
\useequation{3}
Some final text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If using consecutive `equation` environments is wrong, how do you propose having multiple equations in one publication?!

Comment: @user32882 Use `gather` (as I did) or `align`.

Comment: `gather` doesn't allow you to put explanatory text before and after the equation... Please see my response to @David Carlisle

Comment: So, sorry, but it's quite unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think I'm looking for LaTeX to behave like some of the more "common" programming language. In python I'm accustomed to doing something like `x = ["eq1", "eq2", "eq3"]`  and following that with `equation(x) for item in x`. However, I'm realizing that TeX does not really work in this way. I might have to get more familiar with plain TeX to understand how it deals with iteration.

Comment: @user32882 Maybe the additions suit you.

Answer (score 6):

`\@tfor` is part of the LaTeX format:

```
\@tfor\Macroname:=Tokenlist\do{stuff to be done}
```

In order to use `@` in the macro name `\@tfor`, you have to wrap its use within `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (unless the definition is in a file loaded with `\usepackage`). The `%` signs avoid spurious spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\manyequations[1]{%
  \@tfor\Equation:=#1\do{%
    \begin{equation}
      \Equation
    \end{equation}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\manyequations{{a+b}{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2=c^2}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are several looping macros available including `\@for` in the format but it's simpler (and more efficient actually) just to use a custom macro that is directly executed, as all looping macros essentially end up being syntactic sugar around such an execution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}


\section{testing\ldots}
\newcommand\mydo[1]{Some text\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}}

\mydo{a+b}\mydo{a^2+b^2}\mydo{a^2+b^2=c^2}

\end{document}
```